# How do players on a competitive Level in League of Legends use Smartcast?

Tags: league-of-legends

There are actually two ways of smartcasting:

1. You can do it by pressing Shift (default option) + Spell to Smartcast it
2. You can use the Key you configured

I formyself was using the first option all the time. But now I heard that professional players always change their key mapping at the start of every game so they can smartcast without pressing 2 Buttons. (For example I map Smart Cast Q on Q, so I always smart cast it)

Is this the best way to use smart cast? Or how is it usual on the competitive scene?

Comment: I'm VTC this question because I think its too debatable. What works for one player wont neccesarily work for another.

Comment: How is the question "How is it usual on the competitive scene" debatable? I admit that the question what is "best" is very subjective, but the question about how professionals use to play is very clear..

Comment: Some players use shift-QWER, others set it in the options and some even don't use smartcast at all. Everything works and whatever works best for you is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Just a note: your settings save between games, so pros don't actually "change their key mapping at the start of every game."

Comment: Of course the settings save, but the players change their mapping because they play different champs ( and maybe prefer a different key setup then )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to use smartcast is the way which works best for you! But if you are interested which of the top players uses which way, you can do the following:

Go on their stream (own3d.tv / twitch.tv) and wait until they are ingame. At the bottom of the screen, right under each skill, is the button you have to press for the skill (usually Q,W,E,R). IF the boxes where the letters are supposed to be are empty, the player is using the 2nd way. If the box is not empty and the hotkey for the skill is listed he uses the 1st way.